# Aligning `\dot` for a custom command

Tags: renewcommand

For convenience, I'll often create custom commands for variables I'm using often in a document, for example

```
\newcommand{\cartPos}{\ensuremath{x}}
```

This works fine, and I can now do all the usual things like $\dot{\cartPos}$. But if I have something with an underscore, such as

```
\newcommand{\vectorPos}{\ensuremath{r_x}}
```

if I now do `\dot{\vectorPos}`, the dot is applied to the entire object, instead of being aligned above the `r` only, and on in between the variable and the underscore.
Is there a way to deal with this elegantly?

Basically, I would like to get
[image]
instead of
[image]

Comment: You need `\dot{r}_x`, not `\dot{r_x}`.

Comment: I see no reason for `\ensuremath`.

Comment: You can try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/RBRSmyXG).

Comment: @Werner that worked, thanks! Feel free to turn it into a proper answer (a little more explanation will also help for posterity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're defining macros for your vectors, you can redefine `\dot` to condition on whether you're placing it on a vector macro, or something else.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\olddot}{\dot}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\dot}{ m }{%
  \ifx\vectorPos#1
    \olddot{r}_x
  \else
    \olddot{#1}
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\cartPos}{x}
\newcommand{\vectorPos}{r_x}

\begin{document}

$\cartPos ~ \vectorPos$

$\dot{\cartPos} ~ \dot{\vectorPos}$

$\dot{r_x} ~ \dot{r}_x ~ \dot{\vectorPos}$

\end{document}
```

The above option works, but doesn't translate to any general setup easily.